# How to convert a PWM signal generated by an M5 Stack Core ESP32 from 3.3 V or 5 V to 12 V and at least 0.8 A?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, pwm, esp32, voltage-amplification

I am working on a project that requires me to convert two PWM signals of 1 kHz frequency that are generated from an M5-Stack Core from either 3.3 V or 5 V to two PWM signals of 12 V and (at least) 0.8 A. Is there any way of doing this without using a low-pass filter?

I have read on other websites that I can use a low-pass filter to convert it to an analog signal and then use an op-amp to convert it again to a higher voltage signal. Also excuse me if my words don't make much sense. I don't have much experience with circuits. If possible please do use simple vocabulary so I can understand it as better as possible.

Comment: @JRE Thank you for replying so quickly. I implemented the solution with the transistors and it is working perfectly. I do want to ask whether you have a third solution in your mind except the transistor solution and the half H-Bridge motor driver. If you do please do let me know. I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your output is supposed to be PWM, there's no point in filtering the PWM to DC to amplify it.

All you really need is a circuit that switches its output high (to 12V) when the input is high, and switches its output to ground when the input is low.  If you use large transistors for the switching, then you can deliver a large current to your load.

Such a circuit could look like this:

[image]

([From this answer.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/348017/47070))

A simpler way would be to use a [half H-bridge motor driver.](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/IC/SN754410.pdf)  Such a motor driver contains the output transistors and some supporting circuitry to make it easier to use and more robust and reliable